# Is there a type-o in this HackerRank challenge?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, graph-theory

I've spending many hours on this HackerRank problem and I'm confused about what the prompt means. It says

> You are given a tree (a simple connected graph with no cycles). The
>   tree has  nodes numbered from to N.
>        Find the maximum number of edges you can remove from the tree to get a forest such that each connected component of the forest contains
>   an even number of vertices.

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/even-tree

and it has a graph that displays an example.

I'm confused about why it says

> Find the maximum number of edges

Doesn't it mean ***minimum***?

Because if I've trying to maximize the number of edges to remove from

```
      1
   /  |  \ 
  3   6   2
 /    |   / \
4     8  7   5
     / \
    9   10
```

to make it into forests of all even counts then I would keep severing it from the top until I'm at

```
      8  
     / 
    9
```

which is a single forest with an even count.

What the heck am I missing about this? Can someone help clarify?

Comment: Don't ignore the components that have only one vertex. With the way you removed edges results in a forest that has one connected component with even number of vertices (8-9) and eight connected components with odd number of vertices (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10).

Answer (score 0):

> Find the maximum number of edges you can remove from the tree to get a forest such that each connected component of the forest contains an even number of vertices

Note that when you remove an edge from tree, you increase number of connected components by one.
So if you remove `m` edges,   number of connected component of the forest is `m+1`

This question now asks you to find maximum such `m` such that all the connected component will have even number of vertices.

---

If it had been minimum number of edges, answer would have been trivial (0), i.e don't remove any edge!

---

**Hint**

For solving this, for each vertex `v`, maintain count of vertices in subtree rooted at `v`. If this is even, then you can make it as different connected component.